# How do merge specific svn revisions from branch to trunk in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: svn, android-studio, intellij-idea, merge, android-studio-2.0

Some time ago there was a great window where I could choose which revisions I want to merge. And recently the new dialog started to appear. It says :

This will make branch 'https://my_branch' no longer usable for further work. It will not be able to correctly absorb new trunk (https://my_trunk) changes, nor can this branch be properly reintegrated to trunk again.

Are you sure?

But I don't want to reintegrate it. I just want to merge a few revisions. can I still do that in Android Studio

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've find out what was wrong.

It doesn't depend on the version of Android Studio.

**The problem was in wrong path to my trunk location:**

My trunk folder contains multiple folders (yes, it's bad) and in configuration of SVN there was:

https://my_trunk

instead of

**https://my_trunk/my_concrete_trunk_folder**

---

[image]

---

**After I specified location of trunk I got the dialog I wanted:**

---

[image]